# classoid column in pg_description

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

What is the "classoid" column in pg_description table? I see it changing for different kinds of objects like table, function etc.,

The PostgreSQL Official documentations says classoid is "The OID of the system catalog this object appears in", but I don't understand it.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/catalog-pg-description.html

If I'm trying to insert some comments into the pg_description table, is there a specific value based on the object? Like for table --> 1259 for Function --> 1259 etc.,

If that's true, may I know where can I find that list of classoids'?

Comment: oids are generally the primary keys of things in the catalogs. When referenced (via foreign keys), their  names are prefixed with some short string. So, class_oid is the unique identifier of the referenced class. In your case you should look in `pg_class`

Comment: Note that the oids are hidden. For instance `SELECT * FROM pg_class` won't return the oids of the rows but `SELECT oid,* FROM pg_class` will.

Answer (score 3):

They're `oid` values from [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html), which is Postgres' internal list of tables (among other things). The simplest way to work with them is via the [`regclass` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html), e.g.:

```
/* Show catalog table name for all entries */
SELECT classoid::regclass, * FROM pg_description

/* Show all entries referencing pg_proc (i.e. functions) */
SELECT objoid::regprocedure, * FROM pg_description WHERE classoid = 'pg_proc'::regclass
```

However, you really, *really* shouldn't insert into the catalog tables directly. There may be associated entries to add, locks to acquire, validation to do, etc., and unless you know exactly what's going on under the hood, you could easily corrupt your database.

If you want to add an entry to `pg_description`, use a [`COMMENT` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html).

Comment: hello Nick, thanks for the explanation. I'm working on a data migration project (from SQL Server to PostgreSQL). So I want all the COMMENTS in SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I feel the shortest way is to INSERT them in pg_description table. I understood all the rest of the columns except this classoid.

Answer (score 3):

The official docs and the accepted answer here did not add clarity for me, so I'm going to try to restate the answer in a way that might be helpful to others.

`pg_description` has four columns, `objoid`, `classoid`, `objsubid`, and `description`.  `description` has the comment, but the other three values are needed to know exactly what is being commented on.

- `objoid` tells whatyou specific thing in the DB this comment applies to, i.e. what actual table, column, procedure.  But, there is way to know what this is refering to without consulting `classoid`.
- `classoid` is the *type of thing* being described.  This is a foreign key into `pg_class`.  The `relname` column in `pg_class` tells you the type of thing.

`pg_class` is somewhat confusing.  If you do `select * from pg_class where relname = 'my_table'` you will get a result, but this is *not* what `pg_description.classoid` refers to!

`pg_description.classoid` should refer to the entry in `pg_class` with the `relname` of…the string `'pg_class'`.  That is because the *type* of the thing being described is a class.  And, of course, in this case, you then use `objoid` to look up the table in `pg_class`.

To clarify this, suppose `pg_description`'s `classoid` referred to the entry in `pg_class` with the value for `relname` of `'pg_proc'`  That means that `objoid` is a reference to `pg_proc` (*not* to `pg_class`).

OK, so how do you figure out what's what?

```sql
SELECT
  pg_class_objoid.relname AS "Table/View Name",
  pg_description.description
FROM
  pg_description
LEFT JOIN
  pg_class AS pg_class_objoid   ON pg_description.objoid   = pg_class_objoid.oid
LEFT JOIN
  pg_class AS pg_class_classoid ON pg_description.classoid = pg_class_classoid.oid
WHERE
  pg_class_classoid.relname = 'pg_class'
```

This says to join `pg_description.objoid` to `pg_class.oid` and also to make a separate join `pg_description.classoid` to `pg_class.oid`.

We then restrict the results to only those where `classoid` refers to the `pg_class` with the `relname` `'pg_class'`.

Now, if you do this, you'll see a lot of results.  You'll see comments on tables and columns.  This is where `objsubid` comes in.

For the table comments, the `objsubid` is `0`, thus:

```sql
SELECT
  pg_class_objoid.relname AS "Table/View Name",
  pg_description.description
FROM
  pg_description
LEFT JOIN
  pg_class AS pg_class_objoid   ON pg_description.objoid   = pg_class_objoid.oid
LEFT JOIN
  pg_class AS pg_class_classoid ON pg_description.classoid = pg_class_classoid.oid
WHERE
  pg_class_classoid.relname = 'pg_class' AND
  pg_description.objsubid   = 0
```

Will show you what you want.

For completeness, the values of `objsubid` that are *not* 0 but where `classoid` indicates the type of thing is a table/view, the value for `objsubid` should correspond to the value `pg_attribute.attnum` where `pg_attribute.attrelid` equals `pg_description.objoid`.  Thus, to see the table and column comments with their respective names:

```sql
SELECT
  pg_class_objoid.relname AS "Table/View Name",
  pg_attribute.attname AS "Column Name",
  pg_description.description
FROM
  pg_description
LEFT JOIN
  pg_class AS pg_class_objoid   ON pg_description.objoid   = pg_class_objoid.oid
LEFT JOIN
  pg_class AS pg_class_classoid ON pg_description.classoid = pg_class_classoid.oid
LEFT JOIN
  pg_attribute ON pg_attribute.attnum   = pg_description.objsubid AND
                  pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_description.objoid
WHERE
  pg_class_classoid.relname = 'pg_class'
```